# fab button works different in different phones

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

my fab button output in xoloQ600s and Honor5x,I want to my fab button works all device like same.

[image]

below is my code...

In my main layout there is fab button when i click on fab button a fab button menu opens...........layout of menu like this..

fab_layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB"
        app:fabSize="mini" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    FloatingActionButton fab1;
    FloatingActionButton fab2;
    FloatingActionButton fab3;
    FloatingActionButton fab4;
    CoordinatorLayout rootLayout;

    //Save the FAB's active status
    //false -> fab = close
    //true -> fab = open
    private boolean FAB_Status = false;

    //Animations
    Animation show_fab_1;
    Animation hide_fab_1;
    Animation show_fab_2;
    Animation hide_fab_2;
    Animation show_fab_3;
    Animation hide_fab_3;
    Animation show_fab_4;
    Animation hide_fab_4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        rootLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

        //Floating Action Buttons
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_1);
        fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_2);
        fab3 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_3);
        fab4 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_4);


        //Animations
        show_fab_1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab1_show);
        hide_fab_1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab1_hide);
        show_fab_2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab2_show);
        hide_fab_2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab2_hide);
        show_fab_3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab3_show);
        hide_fab_3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab3_hide);
        show_fab_4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab4_show);
        hide_fab_4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab4_hide);


        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (FAB_Status == false) {
                    //Display FAB menu
                    expandFAB();
                    FAB_Status = true;
                } else {
                    //Close FAB menu
                    hideFAB();
                    FAB_Status = false;
                }
            }
        });

        fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Floating Action Button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Floating Action Button 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        fab3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Floating Action Button 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        fab4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Floating Action Button 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



        //Initialize an empty list of 50 elements
        List list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            list.add(new Object());
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        Recycler_View_Adapter adapter = new Recycler_View_Adapter(list, getApplication());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (FAB_Status) {
                    hideFAB();
                    FAB_Status = false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void expandFAB() {

        //Floating Action Button 1
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab1.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.rightMargin += (int) (fab1.getWidth() * 1.5);
        layoutParams.bottomMargin += (int) (fab1.getHeight() * 0.0);
        fab1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        fab1.startAnimation(show_fab_1);
        fab1.setClickable(true);

        //Floating Action Button 2
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab2.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams2.rightMargin += (int) (fab2.getWidth() * 1.00);
        layoutParams2.bottomMargin += (int) (fab2.getHeight() * 0.50);
        fab2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
        fab2.startAnimation(show_fab_2);
        fab2.setClickable(true);

        //Floating Action Button 3
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab3.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams3.rightMargin += (int) (fab3.getWidth() * 0.50);
        layoutParams3.bottomMargin += (int) (fab3.getHeight() * 1.0);
        fab3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
        fab3.startAnimation(show_fab_3);
        fab3.setClickable(true);


        //Floating Action Button 3
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams4 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab4.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams4.rightMargin += (int) (fab4.getWidth() * 0.0);
        layoutParams4.bottomMargin += (int) (fab4.getHeight() * 1.5);
        fab4.setLayoutParams(layoutParams4);
        fab4.startAnimation(show_fab_4);
        fab4.setClickable(true);
    }


    private void hideFAB() {

        //Floating Action Button 1
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab1.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.rightMargin -= (int) (fab1.getWidth() * 1.5);
        layoutParams.bottomMargin -= (int) (fab1.getHeight() * 0.0);
        fab1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        fab1.startAnimation(hide_fab_1);
        fab1.setClickable(false);

        //Floating Action Button 2
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab2.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams2.rightMargin -= (int) (fab2.getWidth() * 1.0);
        layoutParams2.bottomMargin -= (int) (fab2.getHeight() * 0.50);
        fab2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
        fab2.startAnimation(hide_fab_2);
        fab2.setClickable(false);

        //Floating Action Button 3
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab3.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams3.rightMargin -= (int) (fab3.getWidth() * 0.50);
        layoutParams3.bottomMargin -= (int) (fab3.getHeight() * 1.0);
        fab3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
        fab3.startAnimation(hide_fab_3);
        fab3.setClickable(false);


        //Floating Action Button 4
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams4 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab4.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams4.rightMargin -= (int) (fab4.getWidth() * 0.0);
        layoutParams4.bottomMargin -= (int) (fab4.getHeight() * 1.5);
        fab4.setLayoutParams(layoutParams4);
        fab4.startAnimation(hide_fab_4);
        fab4.setClickable(false);

    }

}
```

there a custom animation on it when fab menu open and close....
anim file look like this..

fab1_show.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <!-- Rotate -->
    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromDegrees="30"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="4"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toDegrees="0"></rotate>

    <!--Move-->
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="150%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"></translate>

    <!--Fade In-->
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"></alpha>

</set>
```

fab1_hide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <!--Move-->
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="-150%"
        android:fromYDelta="-0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"></translate>

    <!--Fade Out-->
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"></alpha>

</set>
```

here is main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        />


    <include layout="@layout/fab_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I guess You don´t want to have the second result?

Comment: yes, want to first result

Comment: and the first result is from Honor, am I right?

Comment: first output from xolo

Comment: You might need to use of dimen.xml with required values folder. And set dimen property in your fab.

Comment: But i do not need of dimension...........i am programatically set....fab menu..

Comment: have you given any where size in px means pixel?

Comment: please frnds help me i am in trouble

Comment: No,i do not assign size

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both your devices have different screen densities. In order to get a universal look on all the devices with varying screen densities you need to create different copies of your layout files for each density bracket (low, mid, high, extra-high etc) respectively. These files should be placed in different layout folders according to their density bracket and will have different specifications for margins or paddings etc.

For more information about the density brackets and steps to create these layout folders and files go through the following link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html