# Circular Floating Action Button with Menu

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to develope a view which open on click to floating action button. Basically i need to develope a design which i attached below.
[image: Image Description...]

Comment: Are you looking to do this in Compose or in Views?
It is achievable in both with MotionLayout.

Comment: Both are acceptable Compose or Views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would do it in Views using MotionLayout

Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/circularmenu_scene">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:background="#0178d9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:roundPercent="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/power"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="270"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="180dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/search"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="330"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="200dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/cart"
        android:text="Wishlist"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="300"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="200dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/list"
        android:text="Dashboard"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="0"
        app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="200dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:rotation="45"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        android:src="@drawable/add_circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_circle" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

MotionScene:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="500"
        motion:motionInterpolator="overshoot"
        motion:staggered="0.4">
        <OnClick motion:targetId="@+id/imageButton" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:layout_constraintCircle="@id/background"
            motion:layout_constraintCircleAngle="270"
            motion:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp"
            motion:motionStagger="1" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:layout_constraintCircle="@id/background"
            motion:layout_constraintCircleAngle="332"
            motion:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp"
            motion:motionStagger="1" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:layout_constraintCircle="@id/background"
            motion:layout_constraintCircleAngle="300"
            motion:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp"
            motion:motionStagger="1" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:layout_constraintCircle="@id/background"
            motion:layout_constraintCircleAngle="0"
            motion:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp"
            motion:motionStagger="1" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton"
            motion:motionStagger="2" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:scaleX="2"
            android:scaleY="2"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
            android:rotation="45" >
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="colorFilter"
                motion:customColorValue="#0178d9" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:scaleX="2"
            android:scaleY="2"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
            android:rotation="215" >
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="colorFilter"
                motion:customColorValue="#FFF" />
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

[image: Circle Menu using MotionLayout]

Answer (score 1):

This is how we can make this , check the below code

[image]

```
@Composable
fun CircularFloatingActionMenu() {

    var iconState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = iconState, modifier = Modifier
                .align(BottomEnd)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(BottomEnd)
                    .clip(
                        RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStartPercent = 100,
                        )
                    )
                    .background(Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 0.7f))
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(220.dp)
                        .padding(20.dp)
                ) {
                    ConstraintLayout(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(start = 20.dp)
                    ) {
                        val (dashboard, search, wishlist, logout) = createRefs()
                        AppContent(
                            icon = Icons.Default.MailOutline,
                            text = "Dashboard",
                            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(dashboard) {
                                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                            }
                        )
                        AppContent(
                            icon = Icons.Default.Search,
                            text = "Search",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .constrainAs(search) {
                                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                                }
                                .padding(top = 30.dp, start = 40.dp)
                        )
                        AppContent(
                            icon = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart, text = "Wishlist",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .constrainAs(wishlist) {
                                    top.linkTo(search.bottom)
                                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                                }
                                .padding(top = 15.dp)
                        )
                        AppContent(
                            icon = Icons.Default.ExitToApp, text = "Logout",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .constrainAs(logout) {
                                    top.linkTo(wishlist.bottom)
                                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                                }
                                .padding(top = 20.dp, start = 10.dp)
                        )
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(BottomEnd)
                .padding(20.dp)
        ) {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                iconState = !iconState
            }, backgroundColor = Color.White) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector =
                    if (!iconState) Icons.Default.Add else Icons.Default.Close,
                    contentDescription = "",
                    modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer(
                        rotationZ = animateFloatAsState(targetValue = if(iconState) 180f else 0f).value
                    ),
                    tint = Color.Blue
                )
            }
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun AppContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    icon: ImageVector,
    text: String
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Column() {
            Icon(
                imageVector = icon,
                contentDescription = "",
                tint = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier.align(CenterHorizontally)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))
            Text(
                text = text, style = TextStyle(
                    color = Color.White,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                    fontSize = 14.sp
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

you can modify according to your need. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think someone will answer this for many reasons:

- There's certainly an reveal animation effect that's not mentioned;
- It will take a lot of effort, even if you mention the effect;
- Is a very specfic thing;
- You did not mention what you've already tried.

And I'm not saying this to upset you, but rather help you how to make a better question.

I also tried to find some examples that are not what you expect, but that have a similar context (a fab that reveals other buttons once you click it).

**One tutorial:**
https://www.sitepoint.com/animating-android-floating-action-button

**Two github projects:**
https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

https://github.com/markormesher/android-fab

**One SO answer**
[fab button works different in different phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078187/fab-button-works-different-in-different-phones)

**There's even an example for Jetpack Compose with Material 3:**
https://androidexample365.com/android-library-providing-an-implementation-of-the-material-design-floating-action-button-speed-dial

I hope it helps :)